# FFmpeg Reloading Changed image overlay whilst using a complex filter/

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, reload

I am currently using this code to overlay an image over a stream . I would like to change the image being overlayed regularly. I am using a second script to cp a randomly selected jpg from a folder to a specific folder/advert.jpg every minute. When i run ffmpeg it keeps on using the original image even though the original image in the directory would have been overwritten.

```
ffmpeg  -re  -i  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/251.m3u8" -loop 1 -i "/home/johan/CurrentAd/advert.jpg" -filter_complex "[1]trim=0:600,fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=8:d=2:alpha=1,loop=999:1750:0,setpts=N/5/TB[w];[0][w]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" /var/www/html/sevo/sevo.m3u8  >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Force the generic image muxer:

```
ffmpeg  -re  -i  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/251.m3u8" -loop 1 -f image2 -i ...
```

Without `-f image2`, ffmpeg invokes jpeg_pipe for JPG input, which doesn't update the input with loop set.

Comment: This makes it work , somewhat because sometimes the image changes to the next one mid display . Sadly when it fades out and fades in again the first image is displayed again .

Comment: Just confirming I modified the code as you said and the initial problem of the other images not being loaded has been solved . The filter itself is now the problem cause it keeps on looping the first one or 2 images.

Comment: @mulvya I am using this method to update an overlay on a live stream. I notice that after a period of time ffmpeg stops rendering the updated overlay graphic. Any other methods that would force it to re-render the input?

Comment: *stops rendering the updated overlay* --> does the overlay disappear, or does it stop changing?

Comment: it stopped changing - increasing thread_queue_size for the image inputs seems to have resolved it. been streaming over 24 hours with no probs. I set  my thread queue size to 1024 and ffmpeg still complains it is too small...

Comment: if you require a full screen overlay with transparency i.e. 1280x720 use a tif file, my tests found that ffmpeg requires far less cpu to render a tif overlay compared to other formats supporting transparency, e.g. png.